# Body text render first

Tags: html, web, browser

It is my code:

```
<html>text<head></head><body></body></html>
```

But my firefox browser render that code:

```
<html><head></head><body>text</body></html>
```

Why? Someone know?

Comment: Because text inside `<html>` is invalid and is removed?

Comment: Do you want to put your text before <head> tag? Please explain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
Title goes here
</head>
<body>text</body>
</html>
```

your text should be in body tag that will be display on body.